# Full screen width for a child DIV

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a full width mega menu which stretches 100% width along my browser. However my parent div is stuck inside another div so my 100% width submenu can't get outside of it.

How can I create a sub menu that stretches 100% width across my browser from my parent?

[image]

Comment: post all of the code that you have tried

Answer (score 3):

A quick but not ideal way to do this if you have no control over the HTML is as follows.

```
div.menu {
  position: relative;
  left: -50vw;
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

*Going by memory.*

Basically you use `margin-left` to move it half of the container width to the right, putting the left edge at the centre of the page. Then move the `relative` menu `left` by half of the viewport width (`vw`) so that it's flush with the left of the window. And finally set the `width` to match the viewport.

As long as none of the parent elements have `overflow: hidden;` then this should work well.

This is assuming your page is centred, otherwise @Johannes' solution is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the vw unit (viewport width): `width: 100vw;`

Answer (score 0):

Ok , so here is your code :

```css
*,html,body{
     margin: 0;/*her is the trick*/
     padding: 0;/*her is the trick*/
           }
body,html{
 height: 100%;
      background-color: #f06d06;
      font-family: robotoregular;
}

.parent{
width:300px;
height:100px;
background-color:#eee;
position:relative;/* for the demo*/
}

.child{
position : absolute;/*for the demo*/
bottom:0px;/* for the demo*/
top: 50%;/* for the demo*/
transform: translate(0, -50%);/* for the demo*/
width:100vw;/* Her is the trick !*/
height:50px;
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<h2 style="color:black;text-align:center">I am the parent</h2>
<div class="child">
<h2 style="color:white;text-align:center">I am the child</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

hope it helps.